# How to subclass UITableView with delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I'm subclassing UITableView in my app. It's set up to be it's own delegate.

```
@interface TableView : UITableView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@end

@implementation TableView

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height-144, self.frame.size.width, 40)];

        super.delegate = self;
        super.dataSource = self;
        self.tableFooterView = footerView;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 15;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self.delegate tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"Selected row!");
}

@end
```

Now, what I don't understand is how I TableView can be the delegate of UITableView, but also have a different delegate property that it pipes some functions to sometimes. So, I'd like for - for example - numberOfRowsInSection to be handled by this class, but for - for example - didSelectRowAtIndexPath to be forwarded to the UIViewController or whatever's presenting it.

Comment: if you need a different delegate property, why don't you create  one?

Comment: All are correct except set `self.dataSource=self;` and `self.delegate=self;` as you are defining the related methods in the same class, and move the code to `-(void)awakeFromNib` from `initWithFrame`. By the way I didn't get the purpose of doing this, instead you can separate DataSource in a NSObject class and set to specific tableView, thats best practice.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but let me just go ahead and say: subclassing UITableView and making it's own delegate is a bad idea! You're breaking MVC pattern and you will pay it later. What you should do is subclass UITableViewController and add it as a [child view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) in pour parent controller.

Comment: @deadbeef Would that also work - and be good design - if I'd made it a UIView that adds the UITableView to itself?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In the MVC pattern the views (all subclass of UIView) only manage *how* they appear on screen (colors, fonts, layout, ...). The controller decides *what* should be displayed in it (so typically a UITableViewDelegate is implemented by a controller).

Answer (score 1):

Each of the delegate methods have a property `(UITableView *)tableView` you can use this to identify which table views action to be performed

Eg lets say you have 2 table views **tableView1** & **tableView2** now do something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if tableView == self {
        return [self.delegate tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else if tableView == tableView2 {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

You can do the same concept using super and self calls

**EDIT**

Create a property called `customDelegate`, now in your ViewController set `customDelegate = self` and keep the TableView's delegate same 
Now when you wish the class should handle the call just don't do anything as the behaves would be default

But if you wish that your viewController should handle the call then just pipe it using that customDelegate property

Eg

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if <SOME_CONDITION> {
        // This will cause the TableView's delegate to be called
        return [self.delegate tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else  {
        // We wish the ViewController to handler this action then
        return [self.customDelegate tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I meant. I'm subclassing `UITableView` to a class called `TableView`. I want to be able to set the delegate of `TableView` to `self` in my view controller. Inside `TableView`, however, I want to be able to set it's delegate to self as well. This way all `UITableView` delegate methods will call to `TableView`, which I can then sometimes pipe to the delegate of `TableView`.

Comment: @GirishNair Don't edit user question to post your suggestions

Comment: @TejaNandamuri : Opps sorry